# How do I choose a music player / CD or DVD player?

Tags: audio, speakers, music

I'm looking for a DVD player that will be used only for playing music:

- That can be connected to an amplifier
- A small screen is desirable for playback info
- It should support CDs and USB
- Should be durable

We're not allowed laptops in school, where I intend to use it.

Please recommend a brand/model. My budget is around 3000-5000 INR (OR 50 US$)  but is flexible.

Comment: It's a little hard to answer this because it's very vague. Could you add a possible budget? A bit more specific detail? You could run all of those things off a cheap laptop.

Comment: @EdwardNunn Furthermore, a small $30-40 amplifier w/ USB (maybe closer to $80-100 for one with a screen) and an external DVD drive with a USB connection could probably cover all of OP's requested uses. Post is, indeed, vague.

Comment: The additional info from @jcam3 is also very good, I would look at the options suggested between us.